# How to get current logged user in event receivers?

Tags: event-handlers

I need to get the information about the user actually logged (as SPUser) inside an event receivers.

The following line:

```
Dim currentUser As SPUser = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser
```

does not work because Current is set to Nothing (null).

I read around that this is due to the asynchronous nature of event receivers but then, how to get the user information I need?

**EDIT:** I am using `ItemCheckingIn` receiver to try block a user to check in a file checked out by another user.

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: SPContext will not be available in EventReceiver, hence your Current is returning null.. instead use Properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the synchronous method in your event receiver, and you should be able to retrieve the current user from the context.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. I edited my question to give more details. I am not sure I can use a synchronous event receiver to implement this logic, or yes?

Comment: Synchronous is the only way to go if you want to stop an operation, as you are doing. Strange however, as CurrentContext should be available at this stage...

Comment: Have you also tried properties.CurrentUserId?

Comment: Yes, it worksm thank you! Do you also know how to get SPUser from a CurrentUserId?

Comment: No worries - SPWeb.Users.GetByID() I believe.

Comment: This answer is misleading - it suggests that when Receiver is set to `Synchronous` then `SPContext.Current != null` which is not true. `properties.CurrentUserId` is also available when Receiver is not set to `Synchronous` but in either case it doesn't return SharePoint user ID but some internal number.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
public override void ItemCheckingIn(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    base.ItemCheckingIn(properties);
    var currentUser = properties.Web.CurrentUser;
}
```

As you can see, **properties** object contain **SPWeb**, that have **CurrentUser** property.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code.

```
using (SPSite originalsite = new SPSite(properties.SiteId, properties.OriginatingUserToken))
{
  //To get the current user
  using (SPWeb web = originalsite.OpenWeb())
  {
    string strUserName = web.CurrentUser.LoginName.ToString();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what the behaviour is with async event receivers, but did you have a look at

```
WindowsIdentity windowsIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
```

Comment: This code return me an exception: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

Comment: how to get the current logged in user in the itemadded eventreceiver event ?

Answer (score 0):

With 2010, the event property bag contains the *OriginatingUserToken* ,*UserDisplayName* , and *UserLoginName*, which you can use to get the original user.

Check the section 5.  Impersonation enhancements here : http://extreme-sharepoint.com/2011/12/27/event-receivers-sharepoint-2010/