# Can we find out in Event Receiver group Users like in a CS file

Tags: development, event-receivers, properties

In CS file I used this code and it's worked:

```
  SPWeb site = SPContext.Current.Web;
        int managerGroup = site.Groups["Właściciele witryny Main"].ID;
        if (site.IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(managerGroup))
```

How use in event receiver? Please help.

Comment: To get the spweb you can use properties.web;

Answer (score 1):

I done this like the same method but with direct url:

```
        public bool sprawdzanieUserow()
    {
        SPSite oSiteCollection = new SPSite("http://aaaa/");
        SPWeb site = oSiteCollection.RootWeb;
        int managerGroup = site.Groups["Właściciele witryny Main"].ID;
        if (site.IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(managerGroup))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

'After' Event receivers are launched by system account and therefore you cannot get the current user from its context.

You should check these :
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointdevelopmentlegacy/thread/53c64bb1-6810-48ac-910a-9faa16c8e3b9

[How to get current logged user in event receivers?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/5313/how-to-get-current-logged-user-in-event-receivers)